# How to distinguish beetween two formats of text in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using `HtmlXPathSelector(response)` object in Scrapy, I need to get two kinds of text formats:

My first text has the next format:

```
<p> Text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text </p>
<p>
<p> Text, text, text, text, text. </p>
```

My second text has the next format:

```
Text, text, text, text, text, text
<br>
<br>
Text, text, text..
<br>
<br>
```

when I use `x.select('//div[@id="texto"]/text()').extract()` but not the second... I get something like this:

```
'content': [u'\r\n          ',
                 u'\r\n',
                 ...
                 u'\r\n']
```

when I use `x.select('//div[@id="texto"]/p/text()').extract()` I get the second one but not the first:

How can I use a kind of *rule* in order to get both formats?

**Update:**

I get the solution with the next code, but I feel is a dirty solution:

```
content = x.select('//div[@id="nota_texto"]/p/text()').extract()
if content == []:
    data['content'] = x.select('//div[@id="nota_texto"]/text()').extract()
else:
    data['content'] = content
```

**Update 2:**

Is ok use double slash `//`, however now I am getting the contents of a table, because the HTML has the next format:

```
<div id="texto">
      <table>
        Undesired content
      </table>
       Desired content.
</div>
```

How to avoid get the 'Undesired content'?

**Update 3:**

I received an answer by Steven Almeroth in the Scrapy Users Google Groups:

Use following-sibling:

```
x.select('id("texto")/table/following-sibling::node()').extract()
```

It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want all text inside the div with id "texto" and all it's children?
If that's the case, this should work:

```
x.select('//div[@id="texto"]//text()').extract()
```

If that's too general for you, you can match multiple xpaths using the `|` operator.

```
'<xpath1>|<xpath2>'
```

EDIT:

If the '//text()' xpath gets more than what you want, you should be more specific.
This is where the `|` comes in. Try something like:

```
x.select('//div[@id="texto"]/text() | //div[@id="texto"]/p/text()')
```

Comment: Is ok, however now I am getting the contents of a table, because the HTML has the next format:

    <div id="texto">
      <table>
        Undesired content
      </table>
      Desired content.
    </div>

How to avoid get the 'Undesired content'?

Comment: Thanks, is ok, but I have been discovered a lot of different kind of irregularities in the text like <div> or <fonts>... I get the text like a string and after that parsing with regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Xpath query:

```
string(//div[@id="texto"])
```

Comment: Is util, but I get content I don't want get.